# How do query json for a value?

Tags: javascript, json

Hello :)  How do i find out which "count"-id the loaded picture has?

The loaded picture is: "df5ddc27f7569f83e3867bec71a2cac0.jpg"
And my json are:

```
[
  {"count":1,"file":"8b6c5592f0378dc8c56e591a7b147826.jpg"},
  {"count":2,"file":"a44618c1afe93be486382ceb38536e02.jpg"},
  {"count":3,"file":"3c692942d69fba0d16971e0685f42757.jpg"},
  {"count":4,"file":"df5ddc27f7569f83e3867bec71a2cac0.jpg"}
]
```

Has anybody an idea for me?

Comment: What language?  What have you tried?

Comment: The inital image loads by Get-value on page are loading. The same way i generating a json array with that values above. So i need to know how to findout which "count-id" the initial image has.

Comment: @onbids, you still didn't mention what language you're using or what you've tried that hasn't worked & how's it's gone wrong. Meet us halfway here ;)

Comment: Sorry, i'm using php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to do this with javascript

```
var jsondata = [
  {"count":1,"file":"8b6c5592f0378dc8c56e591a7b147826.jpg"},
  {"count":2,"file":"a44618c1afe93be486382ceb38536e02.jpg"},
  {"count":3,"file":"3c692942d69fba0d16971e0685f42757.jpg"},
  {"count":4,"file":"df5ddc27f7569f83e3867bec71a2cac0.jpg"}
];

function getId(file) {
    for(var f in jsondata) {
       if(jsondata[f].file == file)
         return jsondata[f].count;
    }
}

var id = getId("df5ddc27f7569f83e3867bec71a2cac0.jpg"); //count-id
```

Answer (score 2):

If your image name were a key then you could "query" (index look up) the JSON for its count, like this:

```
var jsondata = [
  "8b6c5592f0378dc8c56e591a7b147826.jpg" : {"count":1},
  "a44618c1afe93be486382ceb38536e02.jpg" : {"count":2},
  "3c692942d69fba0d16971e0685f42757.jpg" : {"count":3},
  "df5ddc27f7569f83e3867bec71a2cac0.jpg" : {"count":4}
];

function getId(file) {
  if(jsondata.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
    return jsondata[file].count;
  } else {
    //Key not Found
    return 0;
  }
}
```

But with the design it currently has you need to iterate over each value (as demonstrated by ocanal's answer) and look for element "file" with the value that equals the image you are after.

Comment: The image i loaded (by GET) hasn't do anything with that json array. It is just here to findout which "count-id"-value has the file with the same "file"-value like the loaded image.